# Twitter api 1.1 is not loading all followers

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a program to get followers details of a person. the code is working fine upto the follower count 3000. i tried with another person which have 200000 Followers. Unfortunately it is showing only 300 followers why this happen? is there any way to fix this?

Here is my code

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', '50000000');     
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');     
$consumerKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$consumerKeySecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$accessTokenSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$settings = array(
  'oauth_access_token' => $accessToken,
  'oauth_access_token_secret' => $accessTokenSecret,
  'consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
  'consumer_secret' => $consumerKeySecret
);

$i = 0;
$cursor = -1;

do {
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json';
  $getfield = '?cursor='.$cursor.'&screen_name=BeingSalmanKhan&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false';
  $requestMethod = 'GET';
  $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
  $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                      ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                      ->performRequest();

  $response = json_decode($response, true);
  $errors = $response["errors"];



  if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach($errors as $error){
      $code = $error['code'];
      $msg = $error['message'];
      echo "<br><br>Error " . $code . ": " . $msg;
    }
    $cursor = 0;
  }
  else {
    $users = $response['users'];
    print_r($users);

    echo'<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>No:</td>';
      echo '<td>Name</td>';
       echo '<td>Profile Description</td>';
        echo '<td>Location</td>'; 
        echo '<td>Followers Count</td>';
         echo '<td>Website Url</td>';
         echo '<td>Screen Name</td>';
         echo '<td>Favourited Tweets</td>';
         echo '<td>Language</td>';
         echo '<td>Friends Count</td>';
         echo '<td>Status</td>';
         echo '<td>Image</td>';


     echo '</tr>';
    foreach($users as $user){
      $thumb = $user['profile_image_url'];
      $url = $user['screen_name'];   
      $name = $user['name'];
      $description = $user['description'];
      $location = $user['location'];
      $followers_count = $user['followers_count'];
      $url = $user['url'];
      $screen_name = $user['screen_name'];
      $favourites_count = $user['favourites_count'];
      $language = $user['lang'];
      $listed_count = $user['listed_count'];
      $friends_count = $user['friends_count'];
      $status = $user['status'];


     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$description.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$location.'</td>'; 
        echo '<td>'.$followers_count.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$url.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$screen_name.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$favourites_count.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$language.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$friends_count.'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$status.'</td>';
         echo '<td><img src="'.$thumb.'"></td>';

     echo '</tr>';
      $i++;
    }
    $cursor = $response["next_cursor"];
  }
}
while ( $cursor != 0 );

if (!empty($users)) {
  echo '<br><br>Total: ' . $i;
}

?>
```

Here is the output what i get

```
 0  Rao.navneet101@gmail        0   
    1   shivangi darshan dos        0   
    2   Renuka.R.K      0   
    3   md samiullah khan   bokaro steel city   0   
    4   monusahu        0   
    5   Vivek mishra        0   
    6   Mezba Alam  Dhaka, Bangladesh.  20  
    7   shiva krishnam raju     0   
    8   shankar rupani      0   
    9   Vasu patil      0   
    10  keerthi     0   
    11  love_guru       1   
    12  abhishek tiwari     0   
    13  Future Care     0   
    14  harikumar sreekumar     3   
    15  Shahnawaz Khan      0   
    16  prakhar bhushan     0   
    17  Binita Chhaparia        0   
    18  venkatesan      1   
    19  Rahul RJ        0   
    20  emty    Abuja Nigeria   12  
    21  Nil-Akash Chy   smart   0   
    22  ashok kumar     1   
    23  azhar       0   
    24  Prarthana       0   
    25  Anu bibu        0   
    26  SAMIR SINGH     0   
    27  Deemag ki Maa Behen.    Saket, New Delhi    35  
    28  abel leo        0   
    29  Dhananjay Pawar     0   
    30  Anuradha Choudhary      1   
    31  maiome.maiome       0   
    32  rahul hussey        1   
    33  vishnupriya     3   
    34  anggi12345      5   
    35  farheen naaz    haora   0   
    36  aman        4   
    37  Shubham Verma   Varanasi(UP)    0   
    38  satish kumar jaiswar        0   
    39  sheikhwasi      0   
    40  MUHAMMADUMAR        0   
    41  Gaurav tiwari   India   0   
    42  arjun malviy        0   
    43  prashanth       0   
    44  saloni      0   
    45  Tanvir,Hridoy       0   
    46  Mahesh Sharma       0   
    47  Deepak Aswathnarayan        2   
    48  devender kumar      0   
    49  Awal        0   
    50  Sanketa Kamble      0   
    51  faraz azhar     1   
    52  Avinash singh       0   
    53  KUMAR SUMIT     0   
    54  Mahuya sultana      0   
    55  hemant chawla       0   
    56  Hanii andiraa       0   
    57  mahendra shah   AHMEDABAD   5   
    58  Angel Preet     0   
    59  kumar gaurav        0   
    60  atul kumar  bangalore   1   
    61  saurabh singh       0   
    62  ajaygadhavi     0   
    63  Prajkta Waditwar    Mumbai  21  
    64  Shruti      1   
    65  Prabhakar Gupta     1   
    66  waseem abbas        0   
    67  Malik Zulqarnain        0   
    68  Sk Azharuddin       0   
    69  MOHIT VIJAY     0   
    70  RadhaKrishnan   chennai 22  
    71  Ruchita Chaudhari       0   
    72  MANISH RAWAT        0   
    73  vyasronit   vansba  0   
    74  SURAJ YADAV     1   
    75  Akanksha Pratik     0   
    76  Sandeep goswami     0   
    77  Rupinder kaur       0   
    78  abhishek pandey     3   
    79  imad        2   
    80  Sandeep rao     0   
    81  sahil khan      0   
    82  abdulbari       95  
    83  Binal Chitroda.     0   
    84  Sexy boy        0   
    85  Akash chauhan       1   
    86  qawserftgyhujik     8   
    87  dhruvil patel       0   
    88  Barada sahoo        0   
    89  Banu        2   
    90  Uddipta kashyap     0   
    91  Mitul sharma    Jammu   0   
    92  pankaj singh    faridabad, haryana  0   
    93  Sanjeev krishnan        0   
    94  adnan ahmed     0   
    95  Ahad sheikh     0   
    96  manish shah Rajkot  5   
    97  VISHAL SINGH        1   
    98  aksahy      1   
    99  satya prasanna  kkd 23  
    100 rajesh rana     0   
    101 Jatt Boys       1   
    102 Zeel Doshi      22  
    103 nabin regmi     1   
    104 aneeta awasthi      0   
    105 navjit k chopra     1   
    106 Ashim Mallick       0   
    107 Rajesh Kumar Mishra     3   
    108 Rahul pagare        0   
    109 Lingam k        0   
    110 Abishek bagmar  chennai 32  
    111 Trang Weinman       0   
    112 muktadesai      0   
    113 mansur.ali2009@gmail        0   
    114 Angel Urvashi   amritsar    1   
    115 rangga nurmansyah       2   
    116 Rajesh Shetty       1   
    117 Muhammad Sohail Akba        1   
    118 waroeng sehat HI        0   
    119 Montibohra      0   
    120 siddarth        1   
    121 SHRAVANI KURRA      0   
    122 suven sarkar        0   
    123 ajit suryawanshi        0   
    124 pappu rakade patil   Babra Aurangabad Maharastra    0   
    125 shiyad shereef      8   
    126 Sachin Ingale   Pune    0   
    127 archana mishra      0   
    128 vijayjaware     1   
    129 Alive Soul      0   
    130 aakash malhotra     0   
    131 sheikh mohsin       0   
    132 Sheryll Franca      0   
    133 Manjeet Mundhe      6   
    134 khan sania  hong kong   0   
    135 vishaldev       0   
    136 grewal laddi        1   
    137 Sanjay kumar        0   
    138 j aishwarya rao     2   
    139 didar khan  oman.sadah  0   
    140 SONI SINGH      0   
    141 mohit khandelwal        2   
    142 sunny verma     1   
    143 Mohinurgazi     0   
    144 Jitender Kumar      1   
    145 Vinay jayakumar     0   
    146 solomonrajesh   chennai 2   
    147 k.nagalakshmi       1   
    148 jeevankiran     9   
    149 Raghu       0   
    150 Alive Chatulistiwa      10  
    151 ses dubey       0   
    152 Sumit Zadafiya      1   
    153 majid abass hassanabad rainawari srinagar   3   
    154 shubh jain      0   
    155 M Fuad      0   
    156 poojashadhijha      0   
    157 manu garg       0   
    158 Imran Hussain       0   
    159 Zain jutt       0   
    160 k.seven new delhi   0   
    161 Lakhan Wanole       1   
    162 Olympia Verrell     0   
    163 majuanwar       0   
    164 Page 29 Kolkata, India  0   
    165 aayushmaan      19  
    166 prashant gupta      3   
    167 jose santha seelan      19  
    168 Mahar Ejaz      1   
    169 kabeer magsi        0   
    170 PriNcE SaMeeR       0   
    171 prashant shrivastava        0   
    172 Vinod Ghorpade      0   
    173 eno apriliani       1   
    174 Pratik Wadkar       0   
    175 FiRu    Kuwait  3   
    176 Jagtap      0   
    177 Ravi kumar  Giridih 0   
    178 Ajay Khandelwal     1   
    179 poojamaurya     0   
    180 Rajat Chouhan       0   
    181 Ayanna Nelms        0   
    182 shrimanth kumar     2   
    183 SATYANARAYNANDWANA      0   
    184 AJEESH  Ayoor,kollam    10  
    185 Shah Alam       1   
    186 Flywell2India   ON L5A 1W7, Canada  3   
    187 banti kashyap   jaipur  1   
    188 ayesha pathan   India   10  
    189 Ranjan SP       44  
    190 AmarDeep        0   
    191 Manish Chamling Rai     0   
    192 Arun kumar      0   
    193 Mitesh Baranwal Varanasi    11  
    194 AKHTAR ABBAS        1   
    195 Toufiq Alahi        0   
    196 Rajbir Singh        2   
    197 Syed Irfan Hussain A        1   
    198 Syed Anwaar Ali indore, India   0   
    199 MD.SOWKAT   Bangladesh  1   
    200 srinivasan      1   
    201 Pradeep Sheler      1   
    202 sagar shergill      0   
    203 mohanvamsi      0   
    204 Keshav Singh        0   
    205 Ankit Verma     0   
    206 vinod kachare       5   
    207 Faraz Imam      3   
    208 Prateek Pathak      16  
    209 Kumar Abhishek      1   
    210 rishita gupta       8   
    211 Krishna Kumar Tiwari        1   
    212 KALIM KHAN      4   
    213 VIPIN       0   
    214 mukund vishwakarma      0   
    215 jitendra mishra     1   
    216 Amit kumar      0   
    217 Tariq       1   
    218 Sonu Jani       0   
    219 Naveen Malethiya    Sri Ganganagar  0   
    220 shyam rajput        0   
    221 Progressive Dental      0   
    222 Aryan sid       0   
    223 simran galhotra     6   
    224 jot singh       0   
    225 vishnukumar.merugu      1   
    226 sujal khandelwal        1   
    227 shashank patel      0   
    228 suhail khan     3   
    229 Vedant Jogdand  Pune    8   
    230 Irfanvali       0   
    231 sakshi vinayak      2   
    232 Amrapali R. Sarodey     0   
    233 ?????       1   
    234 Purnendu Sharma delhi   1   
    235 lhomingdolma lama   Kathmandu, Nepal    0   
    236 humaira khanam      1   
    237 mohammadjawed akhter        1   
    238 Himanshu Rao        0   
    239 sandeep nargunde        1   
    240 yuvarajc        3   
    241 rajesh      0   
    242 Vithika Sheru       0   
    243 himanshu    mumbai, maharashtra 6   
    244 seedtan     0   
    245 nobaiah143billa     0   
    246 saurav dhakal   Nepal   0   
    247 Deep Narayan Rai        1   
    248 sajjad hussain      1   
    249 deepak chandra      2   
    250 Naresh Gorre        0   
    251 priyamaina  assam india 1   
    252 goravsaini      1   
    253 sherlock        0   
    254 Nileshsingh     1   
    255 Aashiqurrahman      0   
    256 Anushka Singh       1   
    257 sumit chhari    mumbai  1   
    258 waquarthakur    Gulaothi    0   
    259 rama karki      1   
    260 pushpa      0   
    261 hasrat      0   
    262 pawan sharma        0   
    263 josey joo       0   
    264 govinda kr. yadav       0   
    265 gurnam singh        1   
    266 MyBusTickets.in India   216 
    267 vicarsonmilco       0   
    268 ANKIT GUPTA     0   
    269 alamin      0   
    270 Kishore     1   
    271 aifazz jr sayed     0   
    272 Salman khan     0   
    273 Dipesh Jha      0   
    274 premkumar       1   
    275 KD Rahees Saifi     2   
    276 Shafiq mastoi       0   
    277 Manvi Agarwal       1   
    278 sumit       1   
    279 manishkumar h patel     1   


    Error 88: Rate limit exceeded

    Total: 300

    280 ajay desai      0   
    281 Umang Pandita   New Delhi   11  
    282 anu rathour     1   
    283 Srinivas Kamath     1   
    284 Pranay Gavhale      1   
    285 pranjal Guwahati    1   
    286 Nani_Tasser     0   
    287 Aryan siddiqui      0   
    288 Karina Noren        0   
    289 samyok subba        0   
    290 sajid malik     0   
    291 Ritesh kanwar       0   
    292 kameshnayak2    raipur  1   
    293 Ashik Babu      1   
    294 Jenifer Bubak       0   
    295 divyansh verma  kanpur  53  
    296 Tothi Monsang   Manipur, India. 0   
    297 vikas pathak        1   
    298 Mohit Rule      1   
    299 asgar ali       3
```

At last i can see a "Error 88: Rate limit exceeded" message.

Thanks.

Comment: @Danny Beckett I added a valid code here.

Comment: Good job; you should get more help now!

Answer (score 1):

At last i got solution for this. This is the only way i found,
Save the last cursor and sent this cursor after 15 minutes as first cursor. it will show another 300 followers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids

Technically, the limit of followers returned each request is 5000.
Are you sure that the count is really 300 in any cases ? Did you display the count of the list you have ?

Comment: Read this first. Rate limit exceeded means that you've made too many requests. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/list

Comment: No i did't make any other requests. even i make request after a hour it showing the same!

Comment: When you're calling a Twitter Request in a do... while loop, don't be surprised that many requests are made.